# Which policy gradient method is used for continuous action spaces?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

Which policy gradient method is used that deals with continuous action spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [Soft Actor Critic](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html) or PPO from the same website. Most [PG methods](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/04/08/policy-gradient-algorithms.html#dpg) can be used in discrete and/or continuous action spaces.